# Backbone view render with multiple model fetch

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, collections, model, fetch

I need to spend 1 model and 1 collection in my html template with backbone. But sometimes, html is ready after the model.
I have :

```
var FormUtilisateurView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(id){
        this.listeClient = new ClientsCollection();
        this.utilisateur = new UtilisateurModel({ id : id });
    },

    render: function(){
        var that = this;
        this.utilisateur.fetch();
        this.listeClient.fetch().done(function(){
            that.$el.html(FormTemplate({ clients : that.listeClient.models, user : that.utilisateur }));

        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

Here, only listeClient collection is loaded.
I want to be sure my model and collection are loaded before the template.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the requests' promises returned by fetch with [`jquery.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to synchronize your rendering task. Something like:

```
render: function(){
    var that = this, promises = [], 
        user = this.utilisateur, clients = this.listeClient;

    promises.push(user.fetch());
    promises.push(clients.fetch());

    $.when.apply(null, promises).done(function(){
        that.$el.html(FormTemplate({clients: clients.models, user: user}));
    });

    return this;
}
```