# Populate Backbone View with multiple Collections

Tags: java, backbone.js, jax-rs, backbone.js-collections

I am new to Backbone.

I am looking a design pattern that work for my situation.

Currently I have a View template which consist of multiple html select:

```
<select id="s1"></select>
<select id="s2"></select>
<select id="s3"></select>
....
```

And going to populate the `select` with multiple Backbone Collections, with different JAX-RS API path.

```
var C1 = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url='/path1'
});

var C2 = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url='/path2'
});

...
```

A straight forward way, is to have a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176171/backbone-view-render-with-multiple-model-fetch):

```
render: function(){
    var that = this, promises = [], 
        c1 = new C1(), c2 = new C2(), c3 = new C3();

    promises.push(c1.fetch());
    promises.push(c2.fetch());
    promises.push(c3.fetch());
    ...

    $.when.apply(null, promises).done(function(){
        that.$el.html(FormTemplate({c1m: c1.models, c2m: c2.models, c3m: c3.models, ...}));
    });

    return this;
}
```

However, this will involve several API calls from the client to the Java server. Is there any way I can achieve this using only 1 API call?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW you should not have `id` attribute in a template. when there's two instances of view your document will be invalid due to duplicate id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the API should provide a single route that returns all data. Then you can fetch it using single collection, and pass filtered data to other collections without them having to make API calls.

Something like:

```js
var SingleEndPointCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url = '/singleEndPoint'
});

var C1 = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

var C2 = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

var C3 = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

var view = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.collection = new SingleEndPointCollection();
    this.collection.fetch({
      success: function(collection, response) {
        that.c1 = new C1(collection.filter(function() {
          // your logic here
        }));
        that.c2 = new C2(collection.filter(function() {
          // your logic here
        }));
        that.c3 = new C3(collection.filter(function() {
          // your logic here
        }));
        that.render();
      }
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    var that = this;
    that.$el.html(FormTemplate({
      c1m: that.c1.toJSON(),
      c2m: that.c2.toJSON(),
      c3m: that.c3.toJSON()
    }));
    return this;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. How about bootstrapped models help in my case? http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap

Comment: @VHanded only helps if this view is your landing page kind of stuff. Loading data for views that needs to be initialized later will only slow loading the initial state of app.